# Filter a NSMutableArray index beyond bounds Problem

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am trying to filter a `NSMutableArray`. Search array for items by certain country.  I have tried `NSpredicate` which works great however I need to re-use the original array which I cannot with `NSpredicate`. So I am trying the below code.

Q. What is the best way to filter an `NSMutableArray` keeping the original array intact?

//The following code works

```
filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < [appDelegate.arrayToBeFiltered count]; i++) {
    id session = [appDelegate.ads objectAtIndex: i];
    id Country = [[appDelegate.arrayToBeFiltered objectAtIndex: i] TheCountry];
    [filteredArray addObject: session];
```

However when I add the if statement as below I get index beyond bounds

```
filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < [appDelegate.arrayToBeFiltered count]; i++) {
    id session = [appDelegate.ads objectAtIndex: i];
    id Country = [[appDelegate.arrayToBeFiltered objectAtIndex: i] TheCountry];
    if (Country == @"United States"){
        [filteredArray addObject: session];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use - (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate

As a side-note, in the code above you probably mean to do this [Country isEqualToString: @"United States"]

As an extra side note - don't capitalise variables and method names. Just a style thing but capitalisation is usually reserved for Class names